# exception occured while trying to run jmx file through java code

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to run the `jmx` file through java code and got below exceptions:

```
INFO    2016-09-01 11:35:53.876 [jmeter.e] (): Listeners will be started after enabling running version
INFO    2016-09-01 11:35:53.896 [jmeter.e] (): To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false
INFO    2016-09-01 11:35:53.899 [jmeter.u] (): Setting Locale to en_US

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConversionException
    at com.staples.mobilautomation.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMeterFromExistingJMX.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Please help me to get closure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `com.thoughtworks.xstream_1.3.0.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: After added jar, got below error, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.configure(Stan‌​‌​dardJMeterEngine.j‌​av‌​a:176) at com.staples.mobilautomation.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMete‌​‌​rFromExistingJMX.j‌​av‌​a:31). <br> i want to update any jar to latest one?

Comment: Looks like a configuration problem

Comment: StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:\\Program Files\\jmeter\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\Program Files\\jmeter\\bin");
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();      
  JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        SaveService.loadProperties();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("F://Stream_Validation.jmx");
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
        in.close();
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();

i have added my code. need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `xstream` jar to your program.

> You can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxstream141jar.htm).

Comment: After added jar, got below error,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.configure(Stan‌​dardJMeterEngine.jav‌​a:176) at com.staples.mobilautomation.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMete‌​rFromExistingJMX.jav‌​a:31). <br> i want to update any jar to latest one?